# HTTP-PUT Request in android

Tags: java, android, http, curl

I want to make an HTTP-PUT request to Amazon S3. It works with curl:

```
curl -v --upload-file file.jpg 'mybucket.amazonaws.com/avatars/cbe7e51de13c1cf93027ab7e14dbd910.jpg?Expires=1419615226&AWSAccessKeyId={MY_KEY}&Signature={MY_SIGNATURE}'
```

the http header looks like this:

```
PUT /avatars/cbe7e51de13c1cf93027ab7e14dbd910.jpg?Expires=1419615226&AWSAccessKeyId={MYKEY}&Signature={MYSIGNATURE} HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0\r\n
Host: mybucket.amazonaws.com\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Length: 130485\r\n
    [Content length: 130485]
Expect: 100-continue\r\n
JPEG File Interchange Format
```

With [loopj](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) I send the following and get 403:

```
PUT /avatars/cbe7e51de13c1cf93027ab7e14dbd910.jpg?Expires=1419615226&AWSAccessKeyId={MYKEY}&Signature={MYSIGNATURE} HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Length: 130745\r\n
    [Content length: 130745]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=86VaLUGmO9qAjHzA98n9F2K-5G812B\r\n
Host: mybucket.amazonaws.com\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "86VaLUGmO9qAjHzA98n9F2K-5G812B"
```

by doing this:

```
            File myFile = new File("image.jpg");
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("", myFile,"");
            client.put(MyApplication.getAppContext(),user.avatarUploadUrl, params, responseHandler);
```

How  can I send a request like curl does with java (no contenttype, no multipart) ?
Because this seems to work for me.

Comment: what httpclient are you use in android?

Comment: this is the one I use: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

Comment: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/432  could check that to see if it matches ur issue

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientChunkEncodedPost.java  diff client (apache httpclient) very easy todo POST on a file using either "inputStreamEntity" or "fileEntity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
    File myFile = new File(file);
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("", myFile);
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("Content-Length" + String.valueOf(file.length()));
    FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity(myFile,"");
    client.put(MyApplication.getAppContext(), user.avatarUploadUrl, fileEntity, null, responseHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure exactly howthe host should look like, but i am sure that with this kind of implementation you can send any request you want.

```
        Socket s = new Socket();
    String host = "aws.amazon.com";
    PrintWriter s_out = null;
    BufferedReader s_in = null;

        try
        {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host , 80));
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //writer for socket
            s_out = new PrintWriter( s.getOutputStream(), true);
            //reader for socket
            s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        }

        //Host not found
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Send message to server
    String Request = "your request";


    System.out.println("Request sent...");


    String response;
    while ((response = s_in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println( response );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found a solution that enables me to use loopj, wich seems to better for consistency